# How to get a domain name from host like `a.b.c.google.co.in` in dart?

Tags: dart

How can we get a domain name from host like `a.b.c.google.co.in` in dart?

By default `Uri.parse` allows you to get a host name but it does not allow you to get a domain name.

In my use case I'm querying `chrome.cookies.getAll` and it requires a user to pass a domain name and not a host name to get correct cookies.

In my use case, I'm only interested in domain name and not the subdomain.

For now I'm using code given below to get domain name from host:

```
  /// returns a domain name using host
  static String getDomainFromHost(String host){
    var splitted=host.split('.');
    var splittedLenght=splitted.length;
    // get the last two
    var domainName='${splitted[splittedLenght-2]}.${splitted[splittedLenght-1]}';
    return domainName;
  }
```

There are sites like facebook that set cookies with domain value `.facebook.com` that are used across various subdomains.

I want to retrieve all cookies that are set using above domain using `chrome.cookies.getAll` API, if I pass a host name, API doesn't provide any results, If I pass a domain name then it provides all results.

Comment: To do this properly you need a library that can understand the [Public Suffix List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) as the length of the domain component is highly variable and unpredictable without that data.

Comment: A host name *is* a domain name. From the perspective of DNS, there's very little difference between `b.c.google.co.in` and `co.in`. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: You also need to use backticks instead of singular quotes to interpolate in JavaScript strings.

Comment: @Sneftel It's a *fully qualified domain name* as in FQDN, which is different from the *registered domain* as in `google.co.in`.

Comment: `google.co.in` is absolutely a FQDN.

Comment: There are sites like facebook that set cookies with domain value `.facebook.com` that are used across various subdomains.

I want to retrieve all cookies that are set using above domain using `chrome.cookies.getAll` API, if I pass a host name, API doesn't provide any results, If I pass a domain name then it provides all results.